# Sql select statement with two foreign key taken from the same table

Tags: sql

```
create table A ( 
    cityID int, 
    cityname nvarchar(30), 
    primary key (cityID)
)

create table b (
    travelID int, 
    fromcityID int, 
    tocityID int, 
    primary key (travelID),
    foreign key (fromcityID) references A (cityID),
    foreign key (tocityID) references A (cityID)
)

insert into A values(1,'amman');
insert into A values(2,'Irbid');

insert into B values(1,1,1)
insert into B values(2,1,2)
insert into B values(3,2,1)
insert into B values(4,2,2)



select travelID, a.cityname,a.cityname  from A, b where ????
```

What should I write in the select statement to view the city name instead of its id?

Comment: Which database are you using? This may affect the syntax of your query.

Comment: I suggest learning about joins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT a.cityname,c.cityname from B b
JOIN A a ON b.fromcityID=a.cityID
JOIN A c ON b.tocityID=c.cityID
```

I have used alias to avoid ambiguity in query.............

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. depending on which database you're using, the syntax may vary

```
select travelID, a1.cityname as city1, a2.cityname as city2
from B
inner join A a1
on a1.cityID = B.fromcityID
inner join A a2
on a2.cityID = B.tocityID
```

Here's a good place to read up on joins http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp